# How can I find out if any k8s resources are using a specific ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am on a GCP k8s cluster. I want to be sure that no pods or other kubernetes resources are using a particular ConfigMap first, before deleting the ConfigMap. Is there a kubectl command that I can use to check what is using a ConfigMap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could export all your resources and grep for the config map name.

You can use this script to export all selected resources (select resources in the RESOURCES category)

```
NAMESPACE="your_namespace"
RESOURCES="configmap secret daemonset deployment service"

for resource in ${RESOURCES};do
  rsrcs=$(kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} get -o json ${resource}|jq '.items[].metadata.name'|sed "s/\"//g")
  for r in ${rsrcs};do
    dir="${NAMESPACE}/${resource}"
    mkdir -p "${dir}"
    kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} get -o yaml ${resource} ${r} > "${dir}/${r}.yaml"
  done
done
```

Next, you can use `grep -nr your_config_map_name your_directory(your name space in this case)`

this will show you the files that contain the config map, I.E resources that use it.